# How to write the limits of triple integral $\iiint f(x,y,z) dz dy dx$ over the annulus?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multiple-integral

How to write the limits of triple integral $\iiint f(x,y,z) dz dy dx$ over an annulus which lies between the circle of radii $r$ and $R$, $r<R$? I am confused. I don't want to change into polar coordinates.

EDIT: I made a mistake in asking my question. It should be the spherical shell region lying between two spheres of radius $r$ and $R$. Sorry!

Comment: $\LaTeX$ note:  You can get a triple integral by writing `\iiint` rather than `\int\int\int` (visually you get $\iiint$ instead of $\int\int\int$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In polar coordinates:

$$\int\limits_{r=r_i}^R \int\limits_{\theta = 0}^{2 \pi} \int\limits_{z=z_i}^{z_f} f(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta,z)\ r\ dr\ d \theta\ dz$$

or in rectilinear coordinates...

$$\int\limits_{x=-R}^R\ dx \int\limits_{y = - \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}}^{+ \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}}\ dy \int\limits_{z=z_i}^{z_f}\ dz\ f(x,y,z) - \int\limits_{x=-r}^r\ dx\ \int\limits_{y = - \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}}^{+ \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}}\ dy\ \int\limits_{z=z_i}^{z_f}\ dz\ f(x,y,z)$$

[image]

Revised question:

$$\int\limits_{x=-R}^R\ dx \int\limits_{y = -\sqrt{R^2 - x^2 - z^2}}^{+\sqrt{R^2 - x^2 - z^2}}\ dy \int\limits_{z=-\sqrt{R^2 - x^2 - y^2}}^{+\sqrt{R^2 - x^2 - y^2}}\ dz\ f(x,y,z) - \int\limits_{x=-r}^r\ dx \int\limits_{y = -\sqrt{r^2 - x^2 - z^2}}^{+\sqrt{r^2 - x^2 - z^2}}\ dy \int\limits_{z=-\sqrt{r^2 - x^2 - y^2}}^{+\sqrt{r^2 -x^2 - y^2}}\ dz\ f(x,y,z)$$

[image]

Comment: G. Stroke, I made a mistake in asking my question. It should be the annular region lying between two spheres of radius $r$ and $R$. Sorry!. Can you please rewrite the limits for this spherical annulus.

Comment: I am not able to vote your comment as I am new here. Thank you!

Comment: I think there is some mistake. When I integrate with respect to z
, shouldn't limits be independent of z? Similarly with other two integrals

Comment: Teeny typo:  fixed.  Thanks.

Comment: David G. Stroke, Sir, how can Change it into spherical coordinates. I that would be easy to evaluate. Also, the function $f(x,y,z)$ is inside the integrals? You have written it like this to make things look simpler, right?

Comment: First:  Please get my name correct.  (You've mis-typed it twice now.) . Second:  Never change your question significantly (e.g., moving to spherical coordinates).  Such "mission creep" is disrespectful of those who have taken the time to help you.  Over and out.

Comment: I am sorry. I don't know all the rules here. I type informally. Sorry. Would be mindful next time. Anyway, I think there is still a problem. As the limits shouldn't contain the variables with respect we are integrating, if I am right?